# Unsupported use of matrix error using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets I have data frame like this:

```
    df <- structure(list(subjecttaxnoid = c("22661187010", "10346575807", 
"22439110996", "63510438612", "85267957976", "40178118040", "51246665873", 
"66803849969", "45813719599", "26979059418", "11240408751"), 
    reportyear = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L), b001 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b002 = c(0, 3.43884233571018e-07, 7.24705810574303e-08, 
    1.41222784374111e-07, 1.62917712565032e-05, 0, 4.53310814208705e-07, 
    7.63856039195011e-06, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("subjecttaxnoid", 
"reportyear", "b001", "b002"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 200000L, 
200001L, 200002L, 200003L, 40000L, 40001L, 40002L, 40003L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the vector that containt names of two columns of df:

```
x <- c("b001", "b002")
```

I would like to use components of x instead of columns names in dplyr:

```
my_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  my_list[[1]] <- df %>% group_by(reportyear) %>% top_n(2, wt = x[1])
}
```

This returns an error:

```
 Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing
```

Could you please help with this issue?

Comment: You've got `for (i in 1:length(x))`, but then `i` never appears in the statement that follows. And nothing in the call to `group_by`? What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I forgot to put variable `reportyear` inside group_by, but that doesn't cghange the error

Comment: I think the error has to do with using strings as variable names in your function when `dplyr` runs on non-standard evaluation, but I can't immediately tell you how to address that.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I trued several solutions like 1) `as.name(x[1])` 2) `noquote(x[1])`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way around this (e.g. by wrapping `x[1]` inside `as.name`) unless you want to change the function `top_n`. The reason like @ulfelder suggested in the comments is that `dplyr` uses non-standard evaluation, so it expects an unquoted variable name in this case. Other functions have versions to handle quoted arguments (e.g. `mutate_`, `rename_`, etc) but not in this case.

The easiest way around it would be to use a temporary assignment , e.g.

```
df %>% 
    group_by(reportyear) %>% 
    mutate_(tempvar = x[1]) %>% 
    top_n(2, wt = tempvar) %>% 
    select(-tempvar)
```

(of course you need to ensure `tempvar` is not a variable name already in your data frame or it will overwrite an existing variable).Far from ideal and you may have thought about this already and rejected it.

Another way is to define your own `top_n_` function which is like `top_n` but expects a string in the `wt` argument:

```
top_n_ <- function (x, n, wt) {
    wt <- as.name(wt)
    stopifnot(is.numeric(n), length(n) == 1)
    if (n > 0) {
        call <- substitute(filter(x, min_rank(desc(wt)) <= n),
            list(n = n, wt = wt))
    }
    else {
        call <- substitute(filter(x, min_rank(wt) <= n), list(n = abs(n),
            wt = wt))
    }
    eval(call)
}
```

This is basically just taking `top_n` and changing the handling of the `wt` argument, at the top of the function definition. Then you can do

```
df %>% group_by(reportyear) %>% top_n_(2, wt = x[1])

identical(
    df %>% group_by(reportyear) %>% top_n_(2, wt = x[1]),
    df %>% group_by(reportyear) %>% top_n(2, wt = b001),
)
# TRUE
identical(
    df %>% group_by(reportyear) %>% top_n_(2, wt = x[2]),
    df %>% group_by(reportyear) %>% top_n(2, wt = b002),
)
# TRUE
```

Comment: Ok, I can write my own function, but that mean that, for every function in dplyr, I have to write my own function if I want to use elements oh character vector as column name?

Comment: Not for every function. There are lots of functions that support character arguments, `select_`, `mutate_`, `rename_` and others. This is one specific example. I think the trick of creating a temporary 'dummy' variable like `tempvar` in my example is an easy way around it if you don't want to write a new function.